# OAuth through HTTP with Twitter

Tags: http, twitter, oauth

I've been using Tweepy for OAuth and twitter API calls. For a whole bunch of reasons, I'm switching to `urllib` and making HTTP requests directly.

It appears have two options:

- I can do oAuth directly over HTTP, but the existing resources seem to either say "don't bother, just use a library," or they don't cover half of the process.
- I can continue using Tweepy to get a key/secret pair, but from there I'm still not clear on how to use that pair to authenticate my queries. Specifically, what do I have to do before "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json" to authenticate, supposing I've already completed the OAuth process and have a key/secret for the user I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a more generic oauth library (like oauth2), instead of throwing out the oauth authentication library idea entirely?

https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2

Signing a request for OAuth means either implementing the signature function yourself for each request or using an existing library - and creating oauth signatures is pretty complicated and prone to breakage.  As someone who's supported OAuth-based APIs for a couple of years I strongly encourage you to use a library.

The oauth2 library has an example for getting a token/secret for twitter.

Once you've gotten the token and secret, the oauth library is as simple as:

```
consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
token = oauth.Token(token,secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer,token)
response = make_request(client,"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json")
```

Comment: Awesome, this is really helpful. However, I;m having trouble finding the example for getting a token you referenced. Is it in the GitHub, and do you have a link?

Comment: Also, where is the make_request function? I can't seem to find it in OAuth2 code anywhere.

Comment: If you go to the github repository for python-oauth2, look for "Twitter Three-legged OAuth Example" on that page (in the Readme, so in the main doc).  That should get you going - it's the example we used as the basis for the LinkedIn Python token docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've been a huge help!